# How to negate test in jinja2

Tags: jinja2

I can filter a list in jinja using selectattr, for example if I want the elements for which foo is None:

```
lists | selectattr('foo','none')
```

but how can I negate this? How can I get all elements for which foo is not none?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`{{ lists | rejectattr('foo', 'none') }}`

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#rejectattr